# C getline() implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, stream

I'm practicing my C coding and I wanted to implement my own version of the `getline` function in C for learning purposes. I'd like a review on coding style, correctness, improvements I can make for performance, and overall quality of the code. My main concerns are correctness and performance (in that order).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 255 

/* Retrieves a line of text from the stream provided
 * and places it into @buf until a new line character is
 * reached or the number of characters read is > @size - 1.
 * This function will null-terminate the provided buffer.
 *
 * @param[in] -- stream -- the stream
 * @param[in] -- buf -- a buffer big enough for @size chars.
 * @param[in] -- size -- the maximum number of chars to read (must
 *    include room for a null terminator
 * @return -- the number of characters read from the stream.
 */
size_t getline(FILE *stream, char *buf, size_t size)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = (char)getc(stream)) != '\n' && count < size - 1) {
        buf[count++] = c;
    }
    buf[count] = '\0';
    return count;
}

int main()
{
   char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
   while (true) {
       size_t count = getline(stdin, line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
       printf("The line gotten was \"%s\" and was %zu chars long.\n", line, count);
   }
}
```

Comment: calling this getline is probably a bad idea, it's nothing like getline().

Answer (score 6):

- Your `getline` function looks more like a variant of [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) than [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).
- If `size == 0`, `size - 1 == SIZE_MAX`, a very large number.
- Your `getline` reads up to `size` bytes from the stream even though it only places only up to `size - 1` into the buffer. It simply drops the last byte silently. You should switch the order of the loop condition:

  ```
  while (count < size && (c = (char)getc(stream)) != '\n') { ... }
  ```
- Your `getline` also writes to memory outside the range defined by its parameters if `size` is 0, when it writes the terminating null byte.
- If `getc(stream) == EOF`, which is an error condition, your `getline` function will keep trying to read from the stream, always "reading" `EOF`, placing `(char) EOF` (usually `'\xff'`) into the buffer until the end of the buffer is reached.

  You can try this by pointing `stdin` at an empty file.
- Use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop, if you're using an iteration counter. It'll be much clearer, what is incremented where and how.

This is how I would rewrite your function considering the above points:

```
ssize_t fgets(FILE *stream, char *buf, size_t size)
{
  if (size == 0)
    return 0;

  size_t count;
  int c = 0;
  for (count = 0; c != '\n' && count < size - 1; count++) 
  {
    c = getc(stream);

    if (c == EOF) {
      if (count == 0)
        return -1;
      break;
    }

    buf[count] = (char) c;
  }

  buf[count] = '\0';
  return (ssize_t) count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There should be some error-checking done here.  For instance, it should return an [`ssize_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), allowing it to return a negative value to indicate an error (anything at or above 0 can be seen as a valid count).  It's also the return type of the [actual function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).